# Draw Polygon Object on ArcGIS IOS map from Latitude and longitudes

Tags: iphone, ipad, arcgis

I am new to ArcGIS IOS map. I need to know the Correct way of Drawing Polygon Object on ArcGIS Map

1. How to convert the Polygon points [Latitude & Longitudes] to Base
   Layer Special Reference ?
2. How to convert the Polygon points [Latitude & Longitudes] to
   `ArcGIS map` required `AGSPoint`?

It will be good if some one share working sample code for these points explanation, so that i can draw the polygon object on Map from Latitudes and longitudes.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You first have to build and AGSPolygon object from latitude and longitudes, then to project the whole polygon to your base layer's spatial reference :

```
AGSMutablePolygon *polygon = [[AGSMutablePolygon alloc] initWithSpatialReference:[AGSSpatialReference wgs84SpatialReference]];
[polygon addRingToPolygon];

for (int i = 0; i < [lats count]; i++) {
    double lat = [lats objectAtIndex:i];
    double lon = [lons objectAtIndex:i];

    //Sub question 2)'s answer
    AGSPoint *point = [[AGSPoint alloc] initWithX:lon y:lat spatialReference:[AGSSpatialReference wgs84SpatialReference]];
    [polygon addPointToRing:point];
}

AGSGeometryEngine *geometryEngine = [AGSGeometryEngine defaultGeometryEngine];
AGSSpatialReference *sr = [[mapView baseLayer] spatialReference];
AGSPolygon *projpolygon = (AGSPolygon *)[geometryEngine projectGeometry:polygon toSpatialReference:sr];
```

Then, you'll probably want to build an AGSGraphic object and add it to an AGSGraphicsLayer, don't forget to specify its spatial reference aswell.

You could also init the polygon with your baselayer's spatial reference and project each point one by one before adding them :

```
//Sub question 1)'s answer
AGSPoint *projPoint = (AGSPoint *)[geometryEngine projectGeometry:wgsPoint toSpatialReference:sr];
```

There are lots of samples on [ESRI's github](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-ios)